# How to start another Activity with android-annotation?

Tags: android-annotations

I'm just trying to use android-annotation. When I start another Activity, an empty activity showed up.
I check this to find that the `@EActivity` generate the subclass of `XXActivity` named `XXActivity_`. So I try to code
`mIntent = new Intent(this, XXActivity_.class);`
But eclipse shows error that `XXActivity_ cannot be resolved to a type`. I don't know when the `XX_` is generated.
I have add the jar, declare the `XX_` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. How to make eclipse generate the XX_ class?

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in this page : https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Eclipse-Only-Configuration ?

Comment: @yDelouis No, I didn't find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could start activity using annotations like this 
first you should write your activities on the manifest file with '_' after that you have two activities you want to go from one to another you could use this :

```
CarDetailActivity_.intent(CarSaleListActivity.this).start();
```

with this you will go the `CarDetailActivity` on the other hand if you want to pass message to the other activity you will use this

```
CarDetailActivity_.intent(CarSaleListActivity.this).myMessage("arrived with android annotations").start();
```

and in this case you should define this on the `CarDetailActivity`

```
@Extra
String myMessage;
```

and you could use this message on `CarDetailActivity` like this on

```
@AfterViews
public void showMessage(){
    Toast.makeText(this,myMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

}
Note : `CarDetailActivity` should be @EActivity to make this work

> Blockquote